# MongoDB Database connection failed to my backend project

Tags: database, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I am using Arch Linux. Recently I installed MongoDB on my OS and when I type show dbs it gives me the exact result. But when I run my backend project using npm start it says database connection failed. Then I check my mongoDB Compass but there was not any database created.

[image: database connection failed]

```js
//database connection
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database Connection Successfull");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Database Connection Failed");
  });
```

here is my database connection source code. here I am using dotenv. In this file I write this code `DATABASE_URL = mongodb://localhost:27017/MEVN_STACK`, When I use Ubuntu it works perfectly but now it isn't working. Please help me to find out the reason.

Comment: Maybe print proper error message instead of generic "Database Connection Failed"

Comment: I got this error when I print the actual error message
`
Server is running on Port: 5000
{ message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017' }
`

Comment: Thanks, @WernfriedDomscheit for your powerful suggestion. I do it and find the actual error and solved finally using this platform. This error occurred for the port. replacing localhost with 0.0.0.0 is works for me.